# RSpec: Creating regex based shared_example-like functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

As a fun project (and maybe a gem if anyone is interested), I'm trying to implement a basic regex matcher (similar to how Cucumber works) whose syntax looks similar to `shared_examples`. But I'm having a hard time understanding RSpec's underpinnings and how to approach this.

Here's what I imagine it looks like:

```
RSpec.describe do
  define_example(/adds (\d+) plus (\d+) and gets (\d+)/) do |a, b, c|
    it { expect(a + b).to eq(c) }
  end

  it_behaves_like_it 'adds 1 plus 1 and gets 2'
end
```

And something like this for implementation:

```
class RegexExample
  attr_accessor :spec_map

  def initialize
    @spec_map = []
  end

  def define_example(regex, &block)
    spec_map << [regex, block]
  end

  def it_behaves_like_it(text)
    spec_map_match = find_spec_map_match(text)

    # Perhaps this should dynamically add a `it` test
    # to the location calling it_behavies_like_it
    it spec_map_match[2] do
      spec_map_match[1].call(*spec_map_match[3])
    end
  end

  private

  def find_spec_map_match(text)
    spec_map.each do |regex, block|
      next unless (match = text.match(regex))
      return [regex, block, text, typecast_captures(match.captures)]
    end
  end

  def typecast_captures(matches)
    matches.map do |m|
      case m
        when /\A\d+\Z/
          m.to_i
        else
          m
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, I can't successfully get it working. I'd like to know if anyone knows a good approach to my problem. If some kind of dependency injection is wise, or if RSpec has a way to do what I'm trying to achieve and I don't realize it. It is working in the sense that it has all the parts to dynamic generate an "it" block, but that's the part I cannot figure out.

Comment: Take a look at custom matchers and shared examples (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)